# Form data with a file and a DTO in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http

I have an endpoint that takes a file and a DTO as form-data:

```
public class FileMetaDataDto
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost( "upload" )]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile( [FromForm]IFormFile file, [FromForm] FileMetaDataDto metaData)
{
   ...
}
```

Using postman, I can successfully hit the endpoint by selecting form-data on the body tab and adding a file, a filename and a version, resulting in this request:

```
POST /test/upload HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 753d374e-a620-4acf-91bd-99a9835757c4
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------857682894806110072741459
Content-Length: 1724
 
----------------------------857682894806110072741459
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mydata.dat"
<mydata.dat>
----------------------------857682894806110072741459
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
test-data
----------------------------857682894806110072741459
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version"
1.0
----------------------------857682894806110072741459--
```

In this case, I have to add each property of the DTO as separate form content. If I try to add the DTO as a single form entry the endpoint doesn't hit:

```
POST /test/upload HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0bbadf29-49f8-48eb-9380-1fd970836b60
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------932600293397405854034879
Content-Length: 1659
 
----------------------------932600293397405854034879
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mydata.dat"
<mydata.dat>
----------------------------932600293397405854034879
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metaData"
{
"filename": "testtest",
"version": "1.2"
}
----------------------------932600293397405854034879--
```

Why doesn't the second request match my endpoint when all the form data is there?

Comment: Why don't you make a complex model? This way shouldn't hit because in postman while sending two `FromForm` as seperate parameter cannnot be passed thus, it wouldn't hit your controller.

Comment: It will create invalid request path as using two `[FromForm]` as seperate parameter is not correct. You ought to create complex model or use one `[FromForm]` and one another type. Together with `[FromForm]` parameter will create invalid request URI and Model.

Comment: So If I create a complex model with only one paramter in the endpoint, the second request should hit? Is still only hitting when I send the first request

Comment: No, your `FileMetaDataDto` model should have `IFormFile` property and method signature should be `UploadFile([FromForm] FileMetaDataDto metaData)` then first `IFormFile` select mime type file and upload the file and provide other property name as usual that would work.

Comment: That's what I did, but there's no difference in how the endpoint can be called it seems like? The first request that I provided still works, the second doesn't

Comment: What's the benefit of having one complex request as opposed to splitting it up like I did?

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the second request match my endpoint when all the form
> data is there?

As explained before, [FromForm] with two seperate parameter will create invalid request URI and Model. Thus, it should have with complex type model as following:

Model:

```
 public class FileMetaDataDto
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UplaodController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost("Upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] FileMetaDataDto metaData)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Postman:

[image]

Swagger:

[image]

> What's the benefit of having one complex request as opposed to
> splitting it up like I did?

No that's what we cannot split this way and your second requst doesn't get hitted because splitting with two [FromForm] have created invalid request model and URI which caused following error behind that caused request failure.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated! When you use postman the way you show here, you get the request I showed in the first example. This will hit both the endpoint with a complex type AND the endpoint where I use two parameters and two [FromForm] attributes. Try it and you’ll see it still works.

Comment: It will hit controller, but are you getting both parameter value?

Comment: Yes, both the file and DTO